# issue with host_defines.h when doing a make

Tags: makefile

I am getting this error

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-53-220:~/EEC-277---GPU-Face-Detect$ make

Linking...
/usr/local/cuda-7.5/bin/crt/link.stub:2:26: fatal error: host_defines.h: No such file or directory
 #include "host_defines.h"
                          ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [detect] Error 1
ubuntu@ip-172-31-53-220:~/EEC-277---GPU-Face-Detect$ locate host_defines
/usr/local/cuda-7.5/targets/x86_64-linux/include/host_defines.h
ubuntu@ip-172-31-53-220:~/EEC-277---GPU-Face-Detect$ head Makefile
CFLAGS  = $(shell pkg-config --cflags opencv)
CFLAGS  += -m32 -I./include,/usr/local/cuda-7.5/targets/x86_64-linux/include/
LIBS        = $(shell pkg-config --libs opencv)
LIBS      += -L/usr/local/cuda/lib -lcudart

KERNELS =   src/kernels/identify1.cu \
                src/kernels/identify2.cu \
                src/kernels/identify3.cu \
                src/kernels/identify4.cu \
                src/kernels/identify_glasses.cu \
```

as per the solutions provided in other questions, i have added the file path in the makefile. i.e the path of the file `host_defines.h` is added to the make file as shown in the head. i found the same question here - http://www.codegur.net/28815117/cuda-missing-host-defines-h-centos-7. no solution. how to fix this ??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I cant be sure, since you haven't given us a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but I think you might have better luck if you changed `-I./include,/usr/local/...` to `-I./include -I/usr/local/...`.

Comment: i tried that also. but no help

Comment: Then you must bite the bullet and prepare a minimal complete example.

Comment: Sure, I'll edit the question to prepare a minimal complete example.